# Url rewriting to page1/ and page1/page2/

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm not sure the title of this post is quite clear...

I have 2 pages : page1.php and page2.php

I would like to have mysite.com/page1 show page1.php and mysite.com/page1/page2 show page2.php

It's the first time of my life I touch to .htaccess. I've added :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^page1/?$    page1.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^page1/page2/?$    page2.php    [NC,L]
```

mysite.com/page1 works fine, but unfortunately mysite.com/page1/page2 shows page1.php (and not page2.php)... without the CSS.

What would you advice ?

Comment: Try removing the space b/w `^` and `page`

Comment: Sorry, actually there is no space in my code

Comment: You have to swap lines.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try your rules this way.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^page1/page2/?$ page2.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^page1/?$ page1.php [NC,L]
```